# How to upload file XLS or XLSX in laravel

Tags: excel, laravel, upload

Is the upload function in laravel only able to upload excel CSV files? How to upload to excel XLS or XLSX files?

Comment: You can upload any files using Laravel. What have you done so far?

Comment: You can upload basically anything, as long as it appears here https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types